# Delete to next search result?

Tags: cursor-motions

I often use `dt`, but that only deletes to a character.  Is there something like `dt` that lets me type in a search instead of a single char?  I would want to delete from my current cursor to that first search term.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this can be done with `d/term<cr>`

Comment: Ah, that's sensible.  I kept trying to do `dt/term<cr>`

Comment: Additionally, if you've already performed the search and want to delete until the next occurrence, you can do `d//<cr>` (or `d//e<cr>` to include the search pattern).